# Mongoose: Search for documents with specified id in the populated document

Tags: node.js, search, document, mongoose, populate

in Mongoose i have two Schemas, which are linked using Mongoose [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html):

```
var SystemSchema = new Schema({
    name                    : {type : String, trim : true}
    , hosts                 : [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Host' }]
});

var HostSchema = new Schema({
    name                    : {type : String, trim : true}
});
```

My question: I have a given ObjectId of a host and now want to see which which Systems do have a reference to that host.

I do this because i normally do access only the SystemsSchema and want to populate the Hosts, but i was asked if i can check the Hosts for Systems as well. Now i tried to simply search and not to populate from Hosts to Systems, but i'm a little stuck.

One of my attempts was to search with where, but this doesn't succeed:

```
System.where('hosts').in(['4fabca804c9d76ac0b000022']).run(function(err, hosts) {
        console.log(hosts);
    });
```

Is there any way to search like this? Please do not tell me to simply put the HostSchema as subdocuments to the SystemSchema, this here is just a simplified example.

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,
Uli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've missed `.populate`

```
 System
    .find({ hosts : '4fabca804c9d76ac0b000022' })
    .populate('hosts')
    .run(function(err, systems) {
         console.log(systems);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, i've somehow mixed some id's, the query above is now working as well. i just need the information above, thus no populate of hosts. Thanks for your answer!